# How to load a view in Master Detail Page, and activate it's child class C# code?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

I hope there is a simple answer to this question because I have been beating my head against the wall for some time now over it, and am ready to move on from trying to achieve what I think should be a relatively easy process.... LOL
What I am trying to do, is populate a templated MasterDetail page from VS2019 with my own views from a project I worked on previously.

After some time I decided to go about loading the views into the master detail using this switch statement

```
  public bool OnNavigationItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
        {
            int id = item.ItemId;
            LinearLayout alt = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.LLTarget);
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)BaseContext.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
            View addView = null;

            if (id == Resource.Id.nav_add)
            {
                alt.RemoveAllViewsInLayout();
                addView = layoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.addDevice, null);
            }
            else if (id == Resource.Id.nav_list)
            {
                alt.RemoveAllViewsInLayout();
                addView = layoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.listDevices, null);
            }
          ... so on and so on...
            if (addView != null)
                alt.AddView(addView);

            DrawerLayout drawer = FindViewById<DrawerLayout>(Resource.Id.drawer_layout);
            drawer.CloseDrawer(GravityCompat.Start);
            return true;
        }
```

The listDevice and addDevice items are XAML pages, with associated view Classes that manipulate, and post-get data from the view,

Here is my problem,
While the code I have here, works beautifully to show the XAML pages. It will NOT call the onCreate() method for the class.
If I load the pages using SetContentView() or StartActivityForResult() I lose the ability to post the view as a sub page of the MasterDetail layout.

Here's a smple of my class layout

```
namespace TestApp2
{
    [Activity(Label = "@string/add_device")]
    public class AddDevice: Activity
    {
        private static NLog.Logger logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

        Spinner spinSubType;
        Button btnAdd;
        EditText ebModel;
        AutoCompleteTextView acMfg;
        EditText ebSerial;
        ImageButton btnPhoto;

        int _imgCount = 0;
        LinearLayout fsCon;
        List<DB.Photos> PhotoCollection = new List<DB.Photos>();
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            logger.Info("Loading form addDevice");
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.addDevice);
        try
        {
            logger.Info("Capturing controls from addDevice.axml");
            spinSubType= FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.typeSpinner);
            acMfg= FindViewById<AutoCompleteTextView>(Resource.Id.acMfg);
            btnAdd = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnAdd);
            ebSerial = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.edSerial);
            btnPhoto = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.imageButton1);
            btnPhoto.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.ic_camera);
            btnPhoto.Click += BtnCamera_Click;
            fsCon = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.fsCon);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        { logger.Error(e.Message); }

        try
        {
            logger.Info("Populating spinner for types");
            LoadStyles(typeSpinner);
            LoadMfg(ebMfg);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { logger.Error(ex); }

        btnAdd.Click += BtnAdd_Click;
        typeSpinner.ItemSelected += new EventHandler<AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs>(Spinner_ItemSelected);
    }
}
```

I know this has to be something insanely easy and simple I am overlooking, probably expecting it to be overly complex and not seeing the obvious simple answer. Or it is somewhat complex, and my google kungfu is too weak...
At any rate, any advice, tips, or ideas would be MOST appreciated!

Cheers!

Comment: you have this tagged as Forms, and mention XAML several times, but the code itself all appears to be native Android?  If that's correct, you should edit the tags/post to reduce confusion.

Comment: The code is the important part to display the forms. The XAML is the content of the form, but has no baring on this issue since I am trying to display it using the Xamarin.Form functions

Comment: if you are purposely trying to mix Forms with native Android code you need to be a lot more explicit about that, and explain what technique that you're using to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Deciding to abandon this idea....
I was using android views, and nesting them within oneanother using a MasterDetail system, but it appears that while this works great for displaying XAML pages, it does not work so well if you are trying to use those pages for data management.
I'm going to start from scratch and build the whole thing using Xamarin.Forms alone.